# Digraph for the "bullet" (8226 hex 2022)

Tags: unicode

I am looking for a digraph to enter the bullet symbol • (Unicode 8226, hex 2022), but it seems there is none. So, in absence of such a digraph, is there an alternative way to enter the bullet easily?

Comment: Use `oo`. (`•  8226`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own digraph like this.

```
:digraph .. 8226
```

Or you could use the pre-existing digraph `Sb` which gives you Unicode 8729.  Not the exact code point you were looking for but it is probably pretty similar visually, if not the same, in most fonts.